# Trying to get a POST to return 400 bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a create method that builds a new model through an association and I was expecting it to return a 400 response with some text if no params were in the POST request. However, I get an error.

This is in Rails 4.0.2

controller methods:

```
  def create
    @cast_profile = current_user.build_cast_profile(cast_profile_params)
    if @cast_profile.save
      redirect_to cast_profile_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def cast_profile_params
    params.require(:cast_profile).permit(:name, :email, :public)
  end
```

If I pass the params its all fine but I'm trying to test the bad request scenario.
Here's the error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: cast_profile
```

I could rescue it explicitly but I thought strong parameters was supposed to do that automatically.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The behaviour is as follows:

> Handling of Unpermitted Keys
>
> By default parameter keys that are not explicitly permitted will be
>   logged in the development and test environment. In other environments
>   these parameters will simply be filtered out and ignored.
>
> Additionally, this behaviour can be changed by changing the
>   config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters property in
>   your environment files. If set to :log the unpermitted attributes will
>   be logged, if set to :raise an exception will be raised.

([source](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#handling-of-unpermitted-keys))

I would suggest rescuing from this exception with 400 status (Bad Request):

```
rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do
  render :nothing => true, :status => :bad_request
end
```

Comment: I'm not having an issue with the handling of unpermitted keys. I'm having an issue with required keys. Further up in the doc you linked it says…

Comment: In addition, parameters can be marked as required and flow through a predefined raise/rescue flow to end up as a 400 Bad Request with no effort.

Comment: I'd like to know what was meant by "no effort". I was under the impression that the 400 response would be automatic without explicitly rescuing.

Comment: Right, my mistake. Seems like there is no such option built-in.

Comment: It looks like everything was working as intended. In the browser (development) I got an error page with a 400 response. It's just the testing env that seems weird. The exception is thrown as expected but, either rails doesn't catch it like it does in dev or minitest gets the error another way and errors the whole test without letting it proceed to the response. So, this seems like a testing issue. I'm still confused though if you have any advice about the testing. In the end I explicitly rescued to make testing possible and to return a 422 since that seemed more correct.

Comment: This issue seems to be still open.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the `400`, you can use `:bad_request`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option