# Rails, how to test 400 response with missing parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, strong-parameters

I'm working with Rails `4.2.5`, and I'm trying to test an expected 400 response from a controller in case of malformed request. The parameter validation logic is handled by `strong_parameters`.

#### the context

In my controller I have:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
end
```

And I'm referencing `user_params` in a POST request with `Accept` and `ContentType` headers set to `application/json`.

In `development`, POSTing without a `user` parameter will raise a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception.
If I set this in my `environments/development.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
end
```

Rails will act like in `production` and return a simple 400 response instead of the debug page. Great.

#### the problem

I'm having troubles doing the same thing in my controller tests, though (`rspec-rails ~> 3.4`).

Specifically, this will pass:

```
expect {
  post :action, malformed_params
}.to raise_error(ActionController::ParameterMissing)
```

but this won't because of the raised exception:

```
post :action, malformed_params
expect(response.status).to eql 400
```

I have already tried to flip the `consider_all_requests_local` for the test environment, to no avail.

Any solution?
There is [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810660/trying-to-get-a-post-to-return-400-bad-request) on this, but it does not help (and even the asker recognized it was not useful).

#### Edit:

As asked in the comments, here are the parameters from the controller spec:

```
let(:user_data) do
  { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz" }
end

let(:good_params) do
  {
    some_id: SecureRandom.uuid,
    user: user_data
  }
end

let(:malformed_params) do
  { some_id: SecureRandom.uuid }.merge(user_data)
end

let(:incomplete_params) do
  { some_id: SecureRandom.uuid }
end
```

`good_params` works for the *happy path*. Neither `malformed_params` nor `incomplete_params` work when I want to test the 400: both will raise the exception and cause the test to fail.

I've already verified that the same parameter payloads will work when POSTing to a running server (in `development`, but with the configuration tweaked as described above).

Comment: How is malformed_parmas ? Could you share it please?

Comment: https://medium.com/@edgar/rspec-how-to-have-rails-request-specs-handling-errors-like-production-a8c21ed0308a

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simulate production across all environments and always raise 400 when any required parameter is missing, instead of changing each config file, you could just put in your controller (or `ApplicationController` or any other mixin to make it more general):

```
# assuming we're talking about a JSON API

rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do |e|
  render json: { error: e.message }, status: :bad_request
end

# or more general for any kind of response

rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do |e|
  head :bad_request
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The exception raised is correct because are not sending a malformed json. 
The payload is formatted well, but is missing a params.

You have to try with something similar at :

```
'{ i am malformed json'
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to validate the JSON syntactical structure. I'm trying to check the response if a parameter is missing, and the response _should_ be 400, not an exception.